# iText and AcroFields styling fonts doubles the fields text

Tags: java, itext, acrofields

i'm facing a problem usintg iText together with java in order to populate form fields.

i've created the form field in a PDF Document using Acrobat 11 Pro and i've been able to populate it with all the values i needed using iText and AcroFields.

Troubles startet to raise when i modified fonts style, size and alignment using Acrobat 11. Now, for each input i modified the style, when i'm using the setField method i get twice the content one that has the aspect i've set in Acrobat 11 and the other that has the default style

Has anyone already tackled that issue?

Comment: Show us the PDF. People who haven't experienced that before can not help you with that issue. There may be very few people who experience the same problem and if there are, they may not be on StackOverflow.

Comment: *Show us the PDF.* - Before and after manipulation, please, and some simple code and your iText version.